# How to get video list in youtube of next page and previos page snippet

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

```
 $playlistItemsResponse = $youtube->playlistItems->listPlaylistItems('snippet', array(
         'playlistId' => $uploadsListId,
         // "nextPageToken"=> '4',
         'maxResults' => 50
     )   
     //"prevPageToken"=> '3'
);
```

I am able to get  first 50 videos snippet

how to retrieve the next 50 video of next page . Kindly suggest me how to pass the parameter

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what library you are using, but you want to grab the nextPageToken and use that parameter in a new request for the next page of results.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list#response

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, for the same {
  "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
  "etag": etag,
  "nextPageToken": string,
  "prevPageToken": string,
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": integer,
    "resultsPerPage": integer
  },
  "items": [
    playlistItem Resource
  ]
}

how to pass next pasge id

Comment: Uncomment the line in your code and pass the nextPageToken from the result of the previous request.